# Revtex generating corrupt .bib file (again)

Tags: revtex

My problem is the same of the author of this post:

[Revtex generating corrupt .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161141/revtex-generating-corrupt-bib-file)

but in that case the problem seemed to be solved when no spaces were included in the filename of the tex file.

In my case this does not apply, since the name of my file is example.tex and I experience the same problem: I use Revtex4-1 and everytime I use the command Latex, I observe that an additional exampleNotes.bib is created from nowhere automatically.

Here my tex file:

```
\documentclass[pop,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\preprint{AIP/Draft1}

\title{Title} %Title of paper

\author{E. Sorolla}
\email{eden.sorolla@xlim.fr}
\affiliation{XLIM, Av. Albert Thomas, 123, Limoges 87100, France.}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
Multipactor is blablabla
\end{abstract}

\pacs{52.80.Pi, 52.80.Vp, 52.20.Dq, 94.05.Pt}% insert suggested PACS numbers in braces on next line

\maketitle %\maketitle must follow title, authors, abstract and \pacs

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
We make an example \cite{Ang_1998} to see whether this works well.

\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

My bib file:

```
%This file was created with JabRef 2.10
%Encoding: Cp1252

@Article{Ang_1998,
Title                    = {Power deposited on a dielectric by multipactor},
Author                   = {L. K. Ang and Y.Y. Lau and R. A. Kishek and R. M. Gilgenbach},
Journal                  = {IEEE Transaction on Plasma Science},
Pages                    = {290-295},
Volume                   = {26},
Year                     = {1998},

Owner                    = {sorolla},
Timestamp                = {2014.01.15}
}
```

Can anyone help to stop generating this file. Do you know why RevTeX insists on generating this extra bib file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With those options, `revtex4-1` puts footnotes among the references; the `exampleNotes.bib` file will contain the footnote texts and is always created, even if no footnote is present. Leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

The `revtex4-1` class, by default, sets footnotes among the references because this is the style of Physical Reviews.

The `<filename>Notes.bib` file will contain the footnote texts. With the following example file `eden.tex`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Ang_1998,
Title                    = {Power deposited on a dielectric by multipactor},
Author                   = {L. K. Ang and Y.Y. Lau and R. A. Kishek and R. M. Gilgenbach},
Journal                  = {IEEE Transaction on Plasma Science},
Pages                    = {290-295},
Volume                   = {26},
Year                     = {1998},

Owner                    = {sorolla},
Timestamp                = {2014.01.15}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[reprint,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to fill in some text

\begin{document}

\preprint{AIP/Draft1}

\title{Title} %Title of paper

\author{E. Sorolla}
\email{eden.sorolla@xlim.fr}
\affiliation{XLIM, Av. Albert Thomas, 123, Limoges 87100, France.}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\pacs{52.80.Pi, 52.80.Vp, 52.20.Dq, 94.05.Pt}% insert suggested PACS numbers in braces on next line

\maketitle %\maketitle must follow title, authors, abstract and \pacs

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
We make an example \cite{Ang_1998} to see whether this works well.
There is also a footnote.\footnote{Some footnote text.}

\lipsum[3-5]

\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(the `filecontents*` environment is used to make the example self-contained) you get the following output

[image]

and the `edenNotes.bib` file contains

```
@FOOTNOTE{Note1,key="Note1",note="Some footnote text."}
```

Thus the file is important and should not be removed.

Comment: What is the difference between a reference and a footnote within the references section?

Comment: @Eden Don't ask me! `;-)` Physical Reviews wants that.